# Receive partial data with timeout using TIdTcpClient

Tags: delphi, indy

How to receive a 100-byte-string with following conditions using TIdTcpClient ?:

- If nothing comes in, the Read call shall be blocking and thread will wait eternally
- If 100 bytes were received the Read call should return the byte string
- If more than 0 bytes, but less than 100 were received, Read call should return after some timeout (say 1 second) in order to return at least something in a reasonable time, without producing timeout exception, because exception handling in Delphi IDE's debug mode hasn't been made convenient.

My not optimal code for now is as follows:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, IdTCPClient;

type
  TTcpReceiver = class(TThread)
  private
    _tcpc: TIdTCPClient;
    _onReceive: TGetStrProc;
    _buffer: AnsiString;
    procedure _receiveLoop();
    procedure _postBuffer;
  protected
    procedure Execute(); override;
  public
    constructor Create(); reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy(); override;
    property OnReceive: TGetStrProc read _onReceive write _onReceive;
  end;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils, Vcl.Dialogs, IdGlobal, IdExceptionCore;

constructor TTcpReceiver.Create();
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  _buffer := '';
  _tcpc := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
  //_tcpc.Host := '192.168.52.175';
  _tcpc.Host := '127.0.0.1';
  _tcpc.Port := 1;
  _tcpc.ReadTimeout := 1000;
  _tcpc.Connect();
  Suspended := False;
end;

destructor TTcpReceiver.Destroy();
begin
  _tcpc.Disconnect();
  FreeAndNil(_tcpc);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TTcpReceiver.Execute;
begin
  _receiveLoop();
end;

procedure TTcpReceiver._postBuffer();
var buf: string;
begin
  if _buffer = '' then Exit;
  buf := _buffer;
  _buffer := '';
  if Assigned(_onReceive) then begin
    Synchronize(
      procedure()
      begin
        _onReceive(buf);
      end
    );
  end;
end;

procedure TTcpReceiver._receiveLoop();
var
  c: AnsiChar;
begin
  while not Terminated do begin
    try
      c := AnsiChar(_tcpc.IOHandler.ReadByte());
      _buffer := _buffer + c;
      if Length(_buffer) > 100 then
        _postBuffer();
    except
      //Here I have to ignore EIdReadTimeout in Delphi IDE everywhere, but I want just to ignore them here
      on ex: EIdReadTimeout do _postBuffer();
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Why not just use [`IOHandler.ReadBytes()`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdIOHandler_ReadBytes@TIdBytes@Integer@boolean.html)instead of trying to do this hard work yourself?

Comment: @Paul I'm pretty sure that Indy handles buffers better than most of us could hope to manage.  If you only want 50 bytes, why ask for 100?  At some point you have a minimum packet size that can make useful sense.  Wait for that packet - if it comes then handle it, if it doesn't then you've nothing to do.  If you don't care about lost data, perhaps UDP is a better protocol than TCP.

Comment: @Paul And rather than trying to read blindly and then dealing with exceptions it's probably better to check the buffer before you try to read (`if not IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then...`).  There's no point trying to read from an empty buffer.  Better yet, if you're reading strings and have control over your command protocol then pick a sensible command terminator and just use `ReadLn`.

Comment: @Paul  Is this a protocol you have designed, or are you following a protocol of some sort?  This approach doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: @Paul Which gets back to my original point that you will have a data packet of some minimum size that is useful to you.  Rather than reading 100bytes or 50 bytes arbitrarily you should be reading a single complete transmission unit, whatever size that may be.  If it's not complete yet, in that case, then there remains no useful information and there is no point to reading part of it.

Comment: TCP is stream oriented, not message oriented. Reading arbitrary bytes without any structure to them is bad design, and will easily corrupt your communications when you stop reading prematurely and then the bytes you wanted to read arrive after you stop reading. They are not removed from the socket until they are read. If you are expecting 100 bytes, then read 100 bytes. If the sender only sends 50 bytes, it needs to tell the receiver that so it can stop reading after 50 bytes are receiving. If your sender is not doing that, then this is  a very poorly designed protocol for TCP.

Comment: And your statement that "*exception handling in Delphi IDE's debug mode hasn't been made convenient*" is rediculous. Indy's `IOHandler` has properties and method parameters for controlling exception behavior, and also if you don't like the way the debugger handles exceptions then configure it to not handle them at all. You can configure the debugger to ignore specific exceptions, or you can use breakpoints to disable the debugger from handling exceptions in specific blocks of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TCP is stream oriented, not message oriented like UDP is.  Reading arbitrary bytes without any structure to them is bad design, and will easily corrupt your communications if you stop reading prematurely and then the bytes you wanted to read arrive after you have stopped reading.  The bytes are not removed from the socket until they are read, so the next read may have more/different bytes than expected.

If you are expecting 100 bytes, then just read 100 bytes and be done with it.  If the sender only sends 50 bytes, it needs to tell you that ahead of time so you can stop reading after 50 bytes are received.  If the sender is not doing that, then this is a very poorly designed protocol.  Using a timeout to detect end-of-transmission in general is bad design.  Network lag could easily cause false detections.

TCP messages should be adequately framed so that the receiver knows exactly where one message ends and the next message begins.  There are three ways to do that in TCP:

1. use fixed-length messages. The receiver can keep reading until the expected number of bytes has arrived.
2. send a message's length before sending the message itself.  The receiver can read the length first and then keep reading until the specified number of bytes has arrived.
3. terminate a message with a unique delimiter that does not appear in the message data.  The receiver can keep reading bytes until that delimiter has arrived.

---

That being said, what you are asking for *can* be done in TCP (but *shouldn't* be done in TCP!).  And it can be done without using a manual buffer at all, use Indy's built-in buffer instead.  For example:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, IdTCPClient;

type
  TTcpReceiver = class(TThread)
  private
    _tcpc: TIdTCPClient;
    _onReceive: TGetStrProc;
    procedure _receiveLoop;
    procedure _postBuffer;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create; reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property OnReceive: TGetStrProc read _onReceive write _onReceive;
  end;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils, Vcl.Dialogs, IdGlobal;

constructor TTcpReceiver.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  _tcpc := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
  //_tcpc.Host := '192.168.52.175';
  _tcpc.Host := '127.0.0.1';
  _tcpc.Port := 1;
end;

destructor TTcpReceiver.Destroy;
begin
  _tcpc.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TTcpReceiver.Execute;
begin
  _tcpc.Connect;
  try
    _receiveLoop;
  finally
    _tcpc.Disconnect;
  end;
end;

procedure TTcpReceiver._postBuffer;
var
  buf: string;
begin
  with _tcpc.IOHandler do
    buf := ReadString(IndyMin(InputBuffer.Size, 100));
  { alternatively:
  with _tcpc.IOHandler.InputBuffer do
    buf := ExtractToString(IndyMin(Size, 100));
  }
  if buf = '' then Exit;
  if Assigned(_onReceive) then
  begin
    Synchronize(
      procedure
      begin
        if Assigned(_onReceive) then
          _onReceive(buf);
      end
    );
  end;
end;

procedure TTcpReceiver._receiveLoop;
var
  LBytesRecvd: Boolean;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    while _tcpc.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty do
    begin
      _tcpc.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(IdTimeoutInfinite);
      _tcpc.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
    end;

    while _tcpc.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size < 100 do
    begin
      // 1 sec is a very short timeout to use for TCP.
      // Consider using a larger timeout...
      LBytesRecvd := _tcpc.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1000);
      _tcpc.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
      if not LBytesRecvd then Break;
    end;

    _postBuffer;
  end;
end;

end.
```

---

On a side note, your statement that "*exception handling in Delphi IDE's debug mode hasn't been made convenient*" is simply ridiculous.  Indy's `IOHandler` has properties and method parameters for controlling exception behavior, and also if you don't like the way the debugger handles exceptions then simply configure it to ignore them. You can configure the debugger to ignore specific exception types, or you can use breakpoints to tell the debugger to skip handling exceptions in specific blocks of code.

Comment: @Paul Indy is well-designed for handling delimiter-based text protocols. The IOHandler has `WaitFor()` and `ReadLn()` methods, and a `ReadLnTimedOut` property. You could `WaitFor` the start character, discarding anything it returns, then `ReadLn` the following characters and check the checksum, then repeat.

Comment: @Paul: I dont use Visual Studio, but regardless of IDE, a debugger ALWAYS gets an exception first, then passes it to the debugged process. This is handled at the OS layer that interacts with the debugger. See [Understanding Exceptions while debugging with Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/01/07/understanding-exceptions-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/). Both  VS and Delphi can be configured to not break on "first chance" exceptions and just let the debugged process handle them normally.

Comment: @Paul: You can utilize the IOHandler's `InputBuffer.IndexOf()` method after calling `WaitFor('$')` to help look for CRLF while handling the 82-byte limit. But you are dealing with a very awkward and horribly designed TCP protocol. Where is this data coming from?

Comment: @Paul: do you have a written spec on this protocol? Please edit your question to provide ALL of the relevant details. Then I'll consider updating my answer to show you how best to deal with it in Indy. You keep changing the details, so now the code currently in my answer is not relevant to your real situation.

Comment: The goal was to decouple parsing from transport. Protocol may change. I would like to have: 1. A range of components with common interface that provide endless chunked character stream. It could be TCP Client, TCP Server, UDP reader, UDP multicast reader, Serial port. All of them have a similar event to pass a string; 2. A range of various parsers that should be independent from protocol used. Multiple parsers of various payloads could be connected to single data retrieval component. As a standard interface between receivers and parsers should be a method `AddMoreCharacters(s: AnsiString)`.